# Evil-mode remap universal-argument to C-f in normal-mode, without weird C-u behavior

Tags: evil

This `.emacs` file is sufficient to reproduce the problem.

```
(package-initialize)
(setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
(require 'evil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-f") #'universal-argument)
(evil-mode +1)
```

However, when I am applying multiple consecutive universal arguments while in normal mode, `C-u` is being treated as universal-argument (which is inappropriate). I can stack both `C-u` and `C-f` and get `C-f C-f C-u C-f C-f` in my modeline. The semantics appear to be the same 4^[number of universal argument things], but I'd like to disable this unwanted behavior and use just `C-f` for universal argument in normal mode.

EDIT:

So it turns out what is actually happening is that after `C-f` the `universal-argument-map` is invoked and in that map the `C-u` key is bound to `universal-argument`. It looks like the purpose of this map and the related transient mode `universal-argument--mode` is to enable digits and - to modify the universal argument after `C-u` has been pressed.

It seems like any solution to this problem would involve defining a function similar to `universal-argument` and binding `C-f` to that.

EDIT:

wasamasa's suggestion works great, but this is what I've settled on so as to avoid modifying the behavior of evil-emacs-state (or when evil-mode is deactivated)

```
(defvar normal-mode-universal-argument-map universal-argument-map
  "swap C-f and C-u in universal-argument-map")
(define-key normal-mode-universal-argument-map (kbd "C-u") nil)
(define-key normal-mode-universal-argument-map
  (kbd "C-f") #'universal-argument-more) 

(defun normal-mode-universal-argument ()
  "universal-argument with C-f and C-u swapped"
  (let ((universal-argument-map normal-mode-universal-argument-map))
    (universal-argument)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remap `C-u` in both the global keymap and the transient one.  Don't forget to map the freed `C-u` in both the global keymap and Evil's normal state keymap to something more useful and to poke a hole in Evil's normal state keymap for the universal argument to be picked up from the global keymap:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-f") 'universal-argument)
(define-key universal-argument-map (kbd "C-u") nil)
(define-key universal-argument-map (kbd "C-f") 'universal-argument-more)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-u") 'kill-whole-line)
(eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  '(progn
     (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-f") nil)
     (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)))
```

Comment: This totally fixes the problem and I think I'll do something similar, but I don't want to mess up emacs-state for the rare occasions I need it.

Comment: Hm, then you could possibly just remap it in Evil's normal state map. You'd still need to do the adjustment in `universal-argument-map` though which would lead the whole reason for not messing up emacs state ad absurdum.

Comment: Is the mapping C-f to transient-map missing here?

Comment: What are you talking about? `C-f` is mapped in both the global map and `universal-argument-map` which is made the current transient map after typing an universal argument. Study `simple.el` for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `define-key` instead of the variable approach

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "\C-u" 'evil-scroll-up)
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I'm on my phone. When I get home I'll format it properly